# condensing locale requests on every program load

Tags: locale, strace, optimization

I ran strace on a number of programs (used syntax strace -fe trace=open --insert program here-- ) and every time I execute a program that automatically forks other processes, I notice lines similar to the following being repeated each time the main program or each child program begins to run:

```
1248  open("/tmp/locale/en_US.UTF-8/LC_MEASUREMENT", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
1248  open("/tmp/locale/en_US.UTF-8/LC_TELEPHONE", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
1248  open("/tmp/locale/en_US.UTF-8/LC_ADDRESS", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
1248  open("/tmp/locale/en_US.UTF-8/LC_NAME", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
1248  open("/tmp/locale/en_US.UTF-8/LC_PAPER", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
1248  open("/tmp/locale/en_US.UTF-8/LC_MESSAGES", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
1248  open("/tmp/locale/en_US.UTF-8/LC_MESSAGES/SYS_LC_MESSAGES", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
1248  open("/tmp/locale/en_US.UTF-8/LC_MONETARY", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
1248  open("/tmp/locale/en_US.UTF-8/LC_COLLATE", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
1248  open("/tmp/locale/en_US.UTF-8/LC_TIME", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
1248  open("/tmp/locale/en_US.UTF-8/LC_NUMERIC", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
```

Is there a way I can condense the above repeated requests by setting certain environment variables or creating certain cache files so that I can see something from this in strace....

```
1248  open("/tmp/locale/en_US.UTF-8/LC_MEASUREMENT", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
1248  open("/tmp/locale/en_US.UTF-8/LC_TELEPHONE", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
1248  open("/tmp/locale/en_US.UTF-8/LC_ADDRESS", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
1248  open("/tmp/locale/en_US.UTF-8/LC_NAME", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
1248  open("/tmp/locale/en_US.UTF-8/LC_PAPER", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
1248  open("/tmp/locale/en_US.UTF-8/LC_MESSAGES", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
1248  open("/tmp/locale/en_US.UTF-8/LC_MESSAGES/SYS_LC_MESSAGES", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
1248  open("/tmp/locale/en_US.UTF-8/LC_MONETARY", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
1248  open("/tmp/locale/en_US.UTF-8/LC_COLLATE", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
1248  open("/tmp/locale/en_US.UTF-8/LC_TIME", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
1248  open("/tmp/locale/en_US.UTF-8/LC_NUMERIC", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
1248  open("/tmp/locale/en_US.UTF-8/LC_MEASUREMENT", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
1248  open("/tmp/locale/en_US.UTF-8/LC_TELEPHONE", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
1248  open("/tmp/locale/en_US.UTF-8/LC_ADDRESS", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
1248  open("/tmp/locale/en_US.UTF-8/LC_NAME", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
1248  open("/tmp/locale/en_US.UTF-8/LC_PAPER", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
1248  open("/tmp/locale/en_US.UTF-8/LC_MESSAGES", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
1248  open("/tmp/locale/en_US.UTF-8/LC_MESSAGES/SYS_LC_MESSAGES", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
1248  open("/tmp/locale/en_US.UTF-8/LC_MONETARY", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
1248  open("/tmp/locale/en_US.UTF-8/LC_COLLATE", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
1248  open("/tmp/locale/en_US.UTF-8/LC_TIME", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
1248  open("/tmp/locale/en_US.UTF-8/LC_NUMERIC", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
...
```

To something like this....

```
1248  open("/tmp/locale/en_US.UTF-8_locales.cache", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
1248  open("/tmp/locale/en_US.UTF-8_locales.cache", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
```

---

Take note that I modified my system so the system locales are located in a special ram-drive locale folder (locale is mounted to a ram drive) in the /tmp folder (most users may see /tmp replaced with /usr/share or /usr/local/share)